# geocoder give me city name in Arabic and English in flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, geocoder

i have used a geocoder package in flutter to get city name depending on the lat and long, after that get all locations with the same city name, and it is working correctly, the problem is some city stored in Arabic languages, and others in English depend on the device language I think, how can I fix this problem? or is there another way to do that, thank you:::

```
final pos = await _determinePosition();
  final List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
    pos.latitude,
    pos.longitude,
    localeIdentifier: 'en_US',
  );
```

Comment: Hello any update on this? Having same issue

Comment: hello, did you manage to solve this problem??

Comment: any news about this?